# Operation on a regular language and context free language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, closure-properties

Given $L_1$ and $L_2$ over some alphabet:

$L_1@L_2 = \{uv \mid u \in L_1 \land v \in L_2 \land |u|=|v|\}$

The question is: if $L_1$ is regular and $L_2$ is context-free, is $L_1@L_2$ context free?

I've been trying to disprove this but to no avail. So I've been thinking to prove this by buiding a PDA but I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that your resulting language will be context free.

Here is a hint for creating a more formal proof.  Try the languages $L_1 = c^*$ and $L_2 = a^nb^n$.  The resulting language, given your additional requirement of $|u| = |v|$ would be $c^{2n}a^nb^n$.

Using the pumping lemma for context free languages, are there two substrings that you can pump indefinitely that will match this language?